# Python more efficient method than .apply()

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have a large dataframe with projected data 60 months into the future, and I need to drop the projections for months that haven't happened yet. I have a functioning way to do this but it's throwing memory errors for a 16 million row dataframe (I have removed all unnecessary columns):

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from tqdm import tqdm
tqdm.pandas()

def add_months(start_date, delta_period):
  end_date = start_date + relativedelta(months=delta_period)
  return end_date

# Apply function on the dataframe using lambda operation.
snapshots["End_Date"] = snapshots.progress_apply(lambda row: add_months(row["startDate"], row["projectedMonth"]), axis = 1)
```

Then I would drop columns where end_date>today. I tried to import 'swifter' but my organisation's settings won't allow that. Is there a more efficient way to deal with this? I wondered about doing

```
snapshots['End_Date']=snapshots['startDate']+relativedelta(months=snapshots['projectedMonth'])
```

But get the error about relativedelta needing int not series. Thanks!

Comment: Filter the rows(?) first, *then* add a column for the rows that remain.

Answer (score 3):

With a lambda function and instead using vectorized operations you could do that, for your case `pd.DateOffset` to add months directly to the date column would be good.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "startDate": pd.date_range(start="2020-01-01", periods=10, freq="MS"),
    "projectedMonth": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
}
snapshots = pd.DataFrame(data)

snapshots["End_Date"] = snapshots.apply(lambda row: row["startDate"] + pd.DateOffset(months=row["projectedMonth"]), axis=1)

today = pd.Timestamp.today()
filtered_snapshots = snapshots[snapshots["End_Date"] <= today]

print(filtered_snapshots)
```

Comment: This would be a much better approach, I got an error 'Units 'M', 'Y', and 'y' are no longer supported, as they do not represent unambiguous timedelta values durations', I guess the unit must've changed in newer python versions?

Comment: yup exact I used a wrong VM, I modified my code now it work for >python 3.6